# read data from struct into 2d array c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to plot coordinates to a map using a 2d Array. The data for the coordinates has been entered by the user and held in a structure. This is a snippet of code taken out of my main program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char map[5][10]={
    "..........",
    "..........",
    "..........",
    "..........",
    ".........."
};

struct coord{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int loop, n, i;

struct coord mg[3];

int main(){

    for(loop=0;loop<3;loop++){
        printf("\n\nEnter MAGENTA X coordinate 0:\n");
        scanf("%d",&mg[loop].x);
        printf("\nEnter MAGENTA Y coordinate:\n");
        scanf("%d",&mg[loop].y);
    }

    printf("Struct contains:\n");

    for(loop=0;loop<3;loop++){
        printf("\tx %d,%d y\n",mg[loop].x,mg[loop].y);
    }

    /*AS SUGGESTED IN ANSWER BELOW (PAUL92),I HAVE DONE THIS BUT GET AN ERROR*/ 

    n=3;
    i=0;    

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         map[mg.y][mg.x] = 'x';
    }

    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

The error I get is

```
testing.c:35:13: error: member reference base type 'struct coord [3]' is not a
  structure or union map[mg.y][mg.x] = 'x';
                         ~~^~
```

What I'm trying to achieve is getting the coordinates held in struct to then be assigned to the correct element in the array i.e. if the user enters 3(x),5(y) then the element map[4][2] will hold this an display and 'x'.

Comment: please, use proper indentation!

Comment: ask yourself a question - what type is `mg`?

Comment: @zoska I would assume that mg is of int type being stored in an array of struct. What are you suggesting?

Comment: The type of `mg` is "array of 3 `struct coord`" - it does not have an `x` member or a `y` member, so `mg.x` or `mg.y` does not exist. Each of the individual elements in the array does have such members, so `mg[i].x` or `mg[i].y` would be fine as long as `0 <= i < 3`... You have this right in other parts of the code (e.g. `mg[loop].x`), so I'm not sure what you intend for `map[mg.y][mg.x]` to be...

Comment: I suggest `mg` does not have `x` or `y` attribute. Why should it, as it's an array? Whence my question - what type is `mg` when you declare it as `struct coord mg[3]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood exactly what you want, but if you want just to mark the points on the map with an 'x' for example, you can to iterate over the points:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    map[mg.y][mg.x] = 'x';
}
```

where n is the number of points.
Of course, this is after you initialize the map.

Comment: Now I have seen it written down it makes perfect sense! I will compile and test it. Thanks @paul92

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect what I implemented following your suggestion. I got an error which I have included in the revised question @Paul92

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the sort of thing I'm after! If I put that into a `for(loop);` that should work a treat! @twalberg